# Zend 2 db transactions?

Tags: database, transactions, pdo, zend-framework2

How do we use transactions in Zend 2? I didn't find anything in the API, and a couple questions for Zend 1 refered to the regular PDO functions, but I don't see anything like that in Zend 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=db;hostname=localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
));

$adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
```

DB will run command:

```
START TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 8):

The documentation is lacking a bit in this department for ZF2:

Start Transaction:

```
$this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
```

Commit Transaction:

```
$this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->commit();
```

Rollback Transaction:

```
$this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->rollback();
```

Comment: But why the result of the var_dump().... begintTransaction() or .... commit() .... or rollback() is NULL  ?

Comment: If you are using MySQL, are your tables in the InnoDB Format? MyIsam does not support Transactions.

Comment: InnoDB, you can check my code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704648/how-do-you-make-to-work-the-database-transaction-in-my-code-in-zend-2/27706751#27706751

Comment: If you change your commit() to rollback() does the insert still happen?

Comment: I switch the commit() with the rollback() and it does not work. what does it mean ?

Comment: Appears your injected adapter was not actually injected. If you open a question I'd be happy to help take a look if you could post your configurations and code examples.

Comment: It in this account i cannot allow for some reason that i am not able to undersand to post more question, but this my question from a another account: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704648/how-do-you-make-to-work-the-database-transaction-in-my-code-in-zend-2/27706751#27706751