# ZF2 Mysql rollback commit function

Tags: mysql, insert, zend-framework2, rollback, multiple-results

I was wondering if there is a function such as mysql rollback commit available in
Zend Framework 2?

I need to insert multiply rows in the same tabel coming from one form submit.

Nick

Comment: The answer was also posted here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228003/zend-2-db-transactions/14259278#14259278

Answer (score 2):

In ZF2, the beginTransaction(), commit() and rollback() methods are in the ConnectionInterface.

As far as I can see, you probably have to write code something like this:

```
$dbAdapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
. . . 
$dbAdapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->commit();
```

See:
http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Db.Adapter.Driver.ConnectionInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be used to update two tables in the same transaction.