# How do you make to work the database transaction in my code in Zend 2?

Tags: transactions, zend-framework2

This is my code from my model :

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;

class UsersTable extends AbstractTableGateway {

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter) {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function fetchAll() {

        $results = $this->adapter->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        $results = $results->execute();
        return $results->current();

    }
    public function insertNewUser($new_user_data){
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        try {
            $x = $this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
            var_dump($x);

            $insert =   $this->adapter->query("INSERT INTO users (username,`name`,email,`password`, birthday,country,city,address,website,img_url,`date`,`update`,ip,email_confirm,`status`) values ('".$new_user_data['username']."','".$new_user_data['name']."','".$new_user_data['mail']."','".md5($new_user_data['password'])."','".$new_user_data['birthday']."','".$new_user_data['country']."','".$new_user_data['city']."','".$new_user_data['address']."','".$new_user_data['website']."','".$new_user_data['user_picture']."',NOW(),
                NOW(),'".$ip."','0','normal')");
            $insert->execute();

            $x = $this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->commit();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->rollback();
            echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage(); 
        }

    }

}
```

The insert query it works fine and it is executed. BUT the result of the var_dump($x) it is null. WHY ? and how do i test it to make sure that it works ? becuase i got no error or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a big deal if $x is null because the method ConnectionInterface::beginTransaction() is supposed to return the Connection itself ($this), it's called [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP).

The fact is that not all the drivers implements it correctly. For example in Mysqli and Pgsql the method has no return.

I'm not sure that it's relevant to use a transaction here ... You've got a single insert, so if it fails there's no need to rollback anything ?

A transaction is usefull when you want several database changes to be atomic (any error in one of theses changes will rollback the whole changes).

Comment: actually it will be more complicated then this, but for the start i just write a simple query. But if i modify the query in order to crash , it will not go to the catch part. why ? I guess the code is wrong. Am i misssing something ? thx

Comment: I take a wild guess here and assume that no exception is thrown within the method hence you'll never run into your catch "condition". For it to throw a exception when the transition fails you'll prob have to extend the behavior and add those yourself. I at this point fail to see as to why you would want to do that can you elobarate on that?

Comment: Maybe you could duplicate your insert so that the 2nd insert throws a duplicate entry exception ... of course one of the columns of the users table should be unique (email ?).